# Extract a word from multiline string

Tags: ansible

I have a multiline string from which I have to extract a word.

Sample String:

```
`Locale LANG set to the following: "en"
Scheduled for (Exp) 02/12/20 (#4662) on CSC2CXN00002555.  Batchman LIVES.  Limit: 80, Fence: 0, Audit Level: 1`
```

I have to extract only the word CSC2CXN00002555. I tried using regex_search ansible module

```
{{ input_string | regex_search('on(.*).  Batchman', multiline=True) }}
```

But I'm getting the whole pattern as output:

```
{
"msg": "on CSC2CXN00002555.  Batchman"
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `regex_replace` if you want to return only a smaller part of your regex.

You can handle the multiline by splitting on newline.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    input_string: |
        Locale LANG set to the following: "en"
        Scheduled for (Exp) 02/12/20 (#4662) on CSC2CXN00002555.  Batchman LIVES.  Limit: 80, Fence: 0, Audit Level: 1

  tasks:

    - name: "it will return 'CSC2CXN00002555'"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ input_string.split('\n') | regex_replace('^.+ on (\\w+)\\.  Batchman .+', '\\1') }}"
```

And for a better understanding of regexes, play with [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Explanation of the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/4RqNb4/1

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex - `CS(.*)5`.

```
{{ input_string | regex_search('CS(.*)5', multiline=True) }}
```